# Is there any save option for the survey?

Tags: support, survey, survey-2017

I was a bit overwhelmed by the length of the survey, and stopped after ~40 questions, intending to continue later on. However, it seems that I have to start over from the beginning. Is there a way to save my progress?

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't even have a *back* button. Pretty sure "save and come back later" isn't on anyone's radar.

Comment: @CodyGray I don't understand the downvote. Do you suspect any reason for it?

Comment: @Honey maybe they're for the unnecessary "rant" at the beginning of your question.

Comment: I've rewritten your question. Feel free to revert if you don't like it, but I think you'll get less downvotes like this.

Comment: @Stijn Thanks it looks much much better. Didn't realize I was being that offensive. has there ever been any discussion about its length?

Comment: @Honey Honestly, questions were a bit more dynamic this year, and some questions only showed if you answered previous questions a certain way. So the team is indeed aware of the length issue, I just imagine it's a difficult balance to strike: Getting the data they need/want vs. Having a shorter survey.

Comment: I have no idea why it was downvoted. I didn't downvote it; I used up all my votes hours ago. Now, all I can do is leave snarky comments. You're welcome. :-)

Comment: *has there ever been any discussion about its length* - That's actually one of the survey questions. Right before you finish they ask if you felt it was too long, short, or OK. I also saw another Meta post about the survey mention it was a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't, unfortunately, have a facility for setting up an account where you can save your progress in the survey.  SurveyMonkey should recognize you when you come back, if you accepted its cookie.  In that case, you will "land" on the last question you had reached and be able to move forward/back through the survey from that point.

Leaving the browser tab open also works.  We've had reports of some respondents doing this being "reset" back to page one, but in those cases their previous responses were saved -- they just had to press the "next" button multiple times to go through.

Comment: I did get punted back to page one once while taking the survey (I'm guessing something timed out while I was looking up salary info). It did save my info but I never saw a back button on the survey. Was the browser's back button supposed to be OK for navigating the survey?

Comment: @BSMP for the first few days, we had the back button (which is labelled "prev" in SurveyMonkey) turned off, but it's turned on now.

Comment: OK, thanks! I did take it pretty early (the 2nd day I think) so that would have been before it was turned back on.